Why does the cache in a GitLab pipeline not work only for a specific pipeline?
I want to use cache in a GitLab pipeline within only a specific pipeline, so other pipelines do not access it. I have written the example below to demonstrate what I mean. In this example, I want to see two files, dist/build and dist/test, in the result job, but I can't.
stages:
    - Build
    - Test
    - Result

cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    paths:
        - dist/

build:
    stage: Build
    script:
        - mkdir -p dist/
        - touch dist/build
    cache:
        - key: $CI_COMMIT_SHA

test:
    stage: Test
    script:
        - mkdir -p dist/
        - touch dist/test
    cache:
        - key: $CI_COMMIT_SHA

result:
    stage: Result
    script:
        - ls dist/
    cache:
        - key: $CI_COMMIT_SHA

Despite setting up the cache, the result job does not find the dist/ directory or the files dist/build and dist/test when running ls dist/. Why can't GitLab handle the cache in this case?

According to this link:

If your job does not rely on the the previous one (i.e. can produce
it by itself but if content already exists the job will run faster),
then use cache.
If your job does rely on the output of the previous one (i.e. cannot
produce it by itself), then use artifacts and dependencies.

So this gitlab-ci.yml can help you:
stages:
    - Build
    - Test
    - Result

build:
    stage: Build
    script:
        - mkdir -p dist/
        - touch dist/build
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - dist/

test:
    stage: Test
    script:
        - mkdir -p dist/
        - touch dist/test
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - dist/

result:
    stage: Result
    script:
        - ls dist/

